# c# AllowAutoRedirect equivalent in Asp.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering something while writing a HTTPWebRequest in ASP.Net Core. 
I do my request correctly and when I have to do set headers for it, before ASP.Net core I was able to do :

```
requestPOST.Method = "POST";
requestPOST.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
requestPOST.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

But now I can't, AllowAutoRedirect dosen't exist it seems, so does the problem come from me and my packages or does AllowAutoRedirect dosen't exist anymore and is there a way to don't allow redirection in another way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler** when AddHttpClient, like:

```
services.AddHttpClient()
   .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
   {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };
   });
```